# How to round up to whole number in R?

Tags: r, rounding

Is it possible to round up to the nearest whole number in R? I have time-stamped data and I want to round up to the nearest whole minute, to represent activities during this minute.

For example, if time is presented in `minutes.seconds` format:

```
x <- c(5.56, 7.39, 12.05, 13.10)
round(x, digits = 0)
[1]  6  7 12 13
```

My anticipated output would instead be:

```
round(x, digits = 0)
[1]  6  8 13 14
```

I understand this is confusing but when I am calculating activity per minute data, rounding up to the nearest minute makes sense. Is this possible?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

We can use `ceiling` to do the specified rounding

```
ceiling(x)
#[1]  6  8 13 14
```